# is there better method use some query instead of group joins

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, left-join

for ex i need select transaction from period 
sum of transaction in the last 3 month 
sum of transaction in the last 4 month 
sum of transaction in the last ... month 
sum of transaction in the last n month

is there better method use sum over or etc

i use query like

```
with 
third as (
select name_id,sum(transaction) from table where pay_Date between add_months(sysdate,-3) and sysdate
group by name_id
),
fourth as (
select name_id,sum(transaction) from table where pay_Date between add_months(sysdate,-4) and sysdate
group by name_id
),
fifth as (
select name_id,sum(transaction) from table where pay_Date between add_months(sysdate,-5) and sysdate
group by name_id
)

select * from third t
left join fourth f on t.name_id = f.name_id
left join fifth f2 on t.name_id = f2.name_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select name_id,
  sum(case when pay_Date between add_months(sysdate,-3) and sysdate then transaction end) sum3,   
  sum(case when pay_Date between add_months(sysdate,-4) and sysdate then transaction end) sum4,
  sum(case when pay_Date between add_months(sysdate,-5) and sysdate then transaction end) sum5
from tablename
group by name_id
```